# Sequential Transformation in Latex Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, expansion

I'm wanting to sequentially transform an object in tikz by using, for example, a `\foreach` and to define a macro for the result after each step iteration. A simple example of what I'm trying to do is below. In my mind, the result should be an "X" at (2,0).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\gdef\Stepi{\node at (0,0) {X};}
\newcount\Counter
\newcount\CounterOneLess

\Counter=1
\CounterOneLess=0
\foreach \i in {2,3}
{
    \global\advance\Counter by1
    \global\advance\CounterOneLess by1
    \expandafter\gdef\csname Step\romannumeral\Counter\endcsname
    {
        \protect\begin{scope}[shift={(1,0)}]
            \csname Step\romannumeral\CounterOneLess\endcsname
        \protect\end{scope}
    }
}

\Stepiii

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, when I try to run pdflatex, I get an error that says the TeX capacity (more specifically the allowable number of grouping levels) is exceeded. I'm guessing the error means I'm inadvertently causing an infinite loop and that it relates to my misunderstanding something about the expansion. Is there a way to get this concept working?

If it helps, the code works if I replace the

`\csname Step\romannumeral\CounterOneLess\endcsname`

inside the scope environment with a `\Stepi`. The result is an X at the expected location (that is, (1,0) in that case). Making this replacement defeats the purpose of course.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What is it you're actually trying to do?  If your interest is in getting something to work, there's probably a much simpler way to do what you want using features of `TikZ` rather than all that `TeX` code.

Comment: It is probably because you are recursively embedding scopes and TikZ already uses a lot of group machinery within macros causing TeX to give up even after three recursions. I'm sure you are aware that you can simply shift the same picture around with a simple macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `\xdef` instead of `\gdef` inside the `\foreach` loop expands the definition text and the current counter values.
- `\noexpand` instead of `\protect` prevents the expansion inside `\xdef`. `\protect` only works with LaTeX macros (`\protected@edef`, ...).

Fixed example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\gdef\Stepi{\node at (0,0) {X};}
\newcount\Counter
\newcount\CounterOneLess

\Counter=1
\CounterOneLess=0
\foreach \i in {2,3}
{
    \global\advance\Counter by1
    \global\advance\CounterOneLess by1
    \expandafter\xdef\csname Step\romannumeral\Counter\endcsname
    {
        \noexpand\begin{scope}[shift={(1,0)}]
            \expandafter\noexpand\csname Step\romannumeral\CounterOneLess\endcsname
        \noexpand\end{scope}
    }
}
\Stepiii
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The business with the counters is not necessary here, because `\foreach` already offers all needed features:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\gdef\Stepi{\node at (0,0) {X};}

\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ioneless using int(\i-1)] in {2,3}
{
    \expandafter\xdef\csname Step\romannumeral\i\endcsname
    {
        \noexpand\begin{scope}[shift={(1,0)}]
            \expandafter\noexpand\csname Step\romannumeral\ioneless\endcsname
        \noexpand\end{scope}
    }
}

\Stepiii

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I appreciate the extra tip about the counters as well.

Answer (score 2):

With fewer `\noexpand` tokens:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineStep}{m}
 {
  \paige_definestep:xx { \int_to_roman:n { #1 } } { \int_to_roman:n { #1 - 1 } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \paige_definestep:nn
 {
  \cs_gset:cpn { Step#1 }
   {
    \begin{scope}[shift={(1,0)}]
    \use:c { Step#2 }
    \end{scope}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \paige_definestep:nn { xx }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \gdef\Stepi{\node at (0,0) {X};}
  \foreach \i in {2,3} { \DefineStep{\i} }
  \Stepi \Stepii \Stepiii
\end{tikzpicture}

\footnotesize
\texttt{\meaning\Stepi}

\texttt{\meaning\Stepii}

\texttt{\meaning\Stepiii}

\end{document}
```

[image]